# htmlentities() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I'm trying to add a class to a laravel form. The array is being passed as the third argument, as required, but I get the above error.

```
{{ Form::input('text', $variable->name, array('class' => 'form-control')) }}
```

If I get rid of the third argument, the form displays as expected (unstyled). I can't see what I'm doing wrong here - can anyone help?

Answer (score 6):

```
{{ Form::text('text', $variable->name, array('class' => 'form-control')) }}
```

Comment: Good point, OP shouldn't even be using `Form::input()`, but `Form::text()`

Comment: up-voted as the best answer.  using `Form::text` is cleaner imo

Answer (score 2):

I can see from the api that there is another argument expected:

http://laravel.com/api/source-class-Illuminate.Html.FormBuilder.html#235-246

```
('text', $name, $value, $options)
```

Answer (score 2):

Your array needs to be the fourth argument to `Form::input()` - the third is the 'default' value. See Laravel's `FormBuilder` class:

```
public function input($type, $name, $value = null, $options = array())
```